# How to make button disabled when checkbox is not checked and vice-versa

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using cakephp and creating a form

```
<?php echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'cancel'));?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php
            echo $form->input('terms', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => __('Terms and Conditions', true)));
            echo $form->hidden('security', array('value' => $security));
            echo $form->end(__('Cancel My Account', true));
        ?>
    </fieldset>
```

Now what i want to do is, initially keep the `"Cancel My Account"` button disabled and only when the checkbox is checked the button should be enabled and hence perform its respective action and similarly vice-versa. I am using the following script to check when the checkbox is checked

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#UserTerms').click(function() {
            var satisfied = $('#UserTerms:checked').val();
            if (satisfied != undefined) {
                $('.cancel-page div.submit input').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('.cancel-page div.submit input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this is not working properly. The button is not getting disabled when the checkbox is unchecked. Please suggest how to make it work.

Comment: In your jQuery you're looking for an element with an ID of "UserTerms". I don't see this being created by the php...

Comment: The ID "UserTerms" is automatically created for the checkbox in cakephp.

Comment: what is not working? does it enter the click event? does it enters the desired if branch?

Comment: Actually initially i didn't make the button disabled so it was not working properly now resolved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion, let me know if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // The function is defined outside the 'document ready' event
    function handleUserTermsChange() {

         // Save jQuery object in variable
        var $userTerms = $('#UserTerms');

        // Bind 'change' event to the checkbox
        $userTerms.bind('change', function() {

            // Save jQuery object in variable
            var $cancelAccountButton = $('.cancel-page div.submit input');

             // If the checkbox is checked..
            if ($userTerms.is(':checked')) {
                $cancelAccountButton.removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $cancelAccountButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }

        }).trigger('change');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // The function is called in the 'document ready' event
        handleUserTermsChange();

    });

</script>
```

- Its $(document), not $('document') - without ''
- No need to define the function on 'document ready',
  you can first define the function and then just call it on document ready.
- Is better to use the 'change' event and not the 'click' event for check-boxes.
- Is better to save the jQuery objects in variables before using them, this way you can always re-use them without creating them again and again
- Is better to check if the check-box is 'checked' instead of checking if its not 'undefined'.
- .trigger('change') its used to run the function once, this way we check for the initial state of the check-box (if it's checked or not when the page loads the first time)

Hope it helps!